# In Jenkins, how can I disable a job's "Discard old builds" via pipeline code?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a lot of Jenkins jobs that has this option enabled in their configuration page
[image: Discard old builds enabled]

How can I disable it via pipeline code so it'll be this?

[image]

Here's the prototype

```
import hudson.model.*

Hudson.instance.getAllItems(Job.class).each {
    if (it.fullName.contains("someJobName")) {
        // Disable "Discard old builds"
        it.discardOldBuilds(disabled) // pseudo code
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it a requirement to do this via a pipeline? There is this plugin which could maybe help https://plugins.jenkins.io/configurationslicing/ and there is the possibility to edit the config.xml on disk with some Linux commands and use "Reload Configuration from Disk" from the jenkins GUI.

Comment: That plugin has NO documentation. I did read other posts that mentioned it, but it seems like it requires one to type in all the jobs that I want. Since I have a lot of them, I'd rather not do that. So yeah, doing it is a pipeline is preferred.

Comment: @ChrisF It does have documentation; just click that link the other poster provided and you'll see it (it's even on a tab labeled "Documentation"). Also, it doesn't require you to type all of the job names in. The text fields are automatically populated with all of the jobs in their current state of configuration. You can just copy/paste from one text field to the other.

Comment: I was having strange issues with my browser yesterday, and the page wasn't showing anything. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Jenkins management **Script Console** to run a system groovy script that will modify the BuildDiscarder for all jobs. You can use something like:

```groovy
def numToKeep = 7
def daysToKeep = 7
def artifactDaysToKeep = -1   // -1 is an empty value
def artifactNumToKeep = -1    // -1 is an empty value


Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(Job.class).each { item ->
  println("******************")
  println("Job Name: ${item.fullName}")
  println("Job type: ${item.getClass()}\n")

  println("Current BuildDiscarder configuration:")
  if(item.buildDiscarder) {
     println("BuildDiscarder: ${item.buildDiscarder.getClass()}")
     println("Current setting: Days to keep=${item.buildDiscarder.daysToKeepStr}; Num to keep=${item.buildDiscarder.numToKeepStr}; Artifact day to keep=${item.buildDiscarder.artifactDaysToKeepStr}; Artifact num to keep=${item.buildDiscarder.artifactNumToKeepStr}\n")
  }
  else {
     println("No BuildDiscarder is configured\n")
  }

  println("Setting new LogRotator settings")
  item.buildDiscarder = new hudson.tasks.LogRotator(daysToKeep,numToKeep, artifactDaysToKeep, artifactNumToKeep)
  item.save()  // save the job with the new config
  println("Job configured")
}
```

This is the basic script for configuring the LogRotator across all jobs.
If you want to disable the configuration you have two options:

1. **Disable the configuration entirely** - (alike your screenshot) In this case you must disable the existing configuration by assigning null to that jobs value.

```
...
 item.buildDiscarder = null // reset the buildDiscarder configuration
 item.save()               // save the job with the new config
...
```

2. **Set all values to -1** - this will leave the LogRotator configuration but with empty values - so it actually doesn't do anything but is still there for future modifications

```
def numToKeep = -1
def daysToKeep = -1
def artifactDaysToKeep = -1
def artifactNumToKeep = -1 
...
item.buildDiscarder = new hudson.tasks.LogRotator(daysToKeep,numToKeep, artifactDaysToKeep, artifactNumToKeep)
item.save() 
...
```

[image]